# Getting "mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting " error while accessing NFS share from CentOS 5 besides it is working fine in CentOS6

Tags: linux

"yum install nfs*"

"yum install portmap"

In `/etc/exports` folder placed below setting in the file

```
/example (NAS drive) *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,fsid=0)
```

Restarted all NFS,nfslock,netfs and portmap services and tried to mount the drive from Ububtu client by using `mount nfs /IPADDRESS/Sharename   /localpath`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is your problem. Perhaps it's from SElinux, firewall, rpcbind or permissions. You should read careful on Security-Enhanced Linux and Managing Confined Services. Your link's [here](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/).

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck nfs server itself has access rights to shared directory

You can inspect directory rights with "ls -la" command:

Example where nfs server does not have access right:

```
cd /your/dir
ls -la
drwxr-x---+  3 user  user  4096 Mar 12 23:17 dir
```

Grant access to user, group and other services:

```
chmod 755 dir
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x+  3 user  user  4096 Mar 12 23:34 dir
```

Restart nfs server and try to mount again.